# Angular application deployment on netlify does not work

Tags: angular, deployment, http-status-code-404, netlify

I am trying to deploy angular application on netlify, I am getting error message. I am not sure why.

```
Page Not Found
Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site
```

[image: Deploy message]

[image: Build settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. `angular.json` contains `outputPath` property whose value needs to be set into netlify`Publish directory.`

Answer (score 2):

On Angular 13 the config is:

Build command: ng build --configuration production

Publish directory: www/